# Documenting a framework with DocC

Tags: swift, xcode, docc

I have a mixed language framework (note: not a Swift package) that contains Swift, Objective-C, Objective-C++ and C++. Right now I'm building documentation with Jazzy, but I'm interested in migrating to DocC for simplified tooling. All the public types are either in Swift or Objective-C.

If I build documentation with Xcode, I get a documentation package that only contains documentation for Objective-C types and for Swift types that are both `public` and `@objc`. Also it looks like [`_documentation(visibility:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_documentationvisibility-) has no effect on them: whatever I specify as the visibility, they show up in the generated documentation.

I can reproduce this behavior with a fresh framework project. A new framework project that contains Swift types that are `public`, `internal` or `private`, `@objc` and not `@objc`, with and without `_documentation(visibility: private)` gives me a documentation package that only contains `@objc public` types, regardless of their documentation visibility level.

This is with both Xcode 15.0 and with Xcode 15.1 beta. Is there anything I do to force Xcode to build docs for the Swift only code too, and to respect the documentation visibility settings?